# How to access to servlet from jsp

Tags: java, servlets

I need to create a small servlet, which keeps text (array of words) and add opportunity to change one word in text to another. For this purpose I created a form:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lab 6</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="LabForm" method="post" action="servlet">
            Old word: <input type="text" name="oldWord"/><br>
            New word: <input type="text" name="newWord"/><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Change">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

On this page I have button *Change* and when I click on it *servlet* which is binded with this form, as you can see, starts it's work. Here's the code of servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Servlet", urlPatterns = {"/servlet"})
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    String arr[] = {"test1",
            "test2",
            "test3",
            "test4",
            "test5",
            "test6",
            "test7",
            "test8",
            "test9",
            "test10",
            "test11"};

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String oldWord = req.getParameter("oldWord");
        String newWord = req.getParameter("newWord");
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        for (int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
            if (arr[i].equals(oldWord)) {
                arr[i] = newWord;
            }
            out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

As it is shown, there's my data (*arr*) displayed. I tried to use this servlet on my main page, but as I understood, if I have button I need to create a href to another page. Please, correct me if I am wrong. But if I want to display my Servlet on the main page (to show user the text and then enter the word he wants to change), what should I do for it. Can I access from my `index.jsp` to servlet in any way? Because I don't want to copy data from servlet in the way like

```
<h2>test1 test2 ... </h2>
```

I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance and hope you have a good day!

Comment: If I understand your question ,the communication between Servlet and JSP did by HTTP request such as AJAX

Comment: You cannot do it this way. Every time you call the servlet the array will change back to how it was originally. You should consider storing that array in like a session object or a text file. There's more than 1 question here, not really sure what you want to achieve